# Memory footprint estimation in Java

Tags: java, jamm

I am developing a class which will represent a set of rows from a table in Java. The rows could be in either compact or extended format. One can detect the internal format in the object using a function call.

I was trying to write a unit test to understand memory footprint of this object in compact and extended format. I used memorymeter https://github.com/jbellis/jamm) for this. I noticed that the deep size of the object is being shown to be different even when the underlying data remains the same in different runs. I am a bit confused with this. My expectation is that traversal through object graph should give me correct estimate of sizeof(object). Could this be an issue with the package I am using or is my expectation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code under test uses lazy initialization, or the test cases perform different operations, the actual instances in memory may differ in count, size, and occasionally even type.

I would verify that your different runs are using the same test case, and if they are not, I would not assume that the memory consumption with the same input would be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When you say "equivalent" for same test case, do you mean same number (for example : 550 bytes for each run) or small difference? In C++, sizeof() provides a very precise estimate on a given platform.